# Can I use Synaptics' output in KVM?

Tags: xorg, virtualization, kvm, touchpad

I have been looking at MenuetOS, a simple graphical OS written entirely in FASM. The only reason I don't actually use it is that its touchpad support is pure garbage: every time I try to run MenuetOS, I struggle to control the cursor and I have difficulty doing simple things like closing windows. There is no keyboard-based navigation interface that I am aware of.

Obviously I won't be able to run MenuetOS on this hardware, but I hoped I could run it in KVM. KVM normally allows the OS to use the input from the touchpad directly, so it doesn't solve the problem, but I was hoping that I could get X to intervene.

Is it possible to force KVM to use the cursor position data generated by X's Synaptics touchpad driver instead of the raw touchpad input?